# GROUP BY não funciona no MySQL 5.7

Tags: mysql, group-by

Localmente tenho o MySQL 5.6 instalado, e esse SELECT funciona sem problemas:

```
SELECT dia FROM indicacao
GROUP BY YEAR(dia), MONTH(dia)
ORDER BY dia DESC
```

Já no servidor do cliente, com MySQL 5.7 esse mesmo SELECT não funciona. Percebo que o problema está no GROUP BY, pois se retiro, funciona. Se eu faço um SELECT sem PDO ele simplesmente não retorna nada... se eu faço esse mesmo SELECT com PDO da erro 500 no servidor.

O conteúdo do banco de dados é igual (localmente e no servidor do cliente). Alguém já passou por isso?
Sabe se pode ser alguma configuração do servidor?
Existe algo que possa usar para testar ou ver algum log de erro?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Isso ocorre porque o MySQL 5.7 agora é padronizado como ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY ativado.

Para desabilitá-lo:

1) Vá até a pasta bin onde tem a instalação do seu MySQL (no caso do  meu computador é: C:\WAMP\MySQL\5.6.42\bin):
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

2) Execute o executável de nome mysql.exe e exibirá a janela de command line do MySQL:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

3) Execute um dos comandos abaixo para desativar:

```
mysql > SET GLOBAL sql_mode=(SELECT REPLACE(@@sql_mode,'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY',''));
```

ou

```
SET sql_mode = '';
```

Se quiser habitá-lo novamente em outro momento é só executar este comando:

```
SET sql_mode = 'ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY';
```

Após irá exibir uma mensagem de 'Query ok' quando executado com sucesso.
[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Para saber mais sobre o ONLY_FULL_GROUP_BY acesse este [link](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/group-by-handling.html).

Comment: Obrigado! Onde coloco isso?

Comment: Vou editar na resposta mostrando onde é com prints